# 2 drives, one has Boot, the other has System

Tags: windows-10, boot

I have 2 hard drives but the dilemma is: One drive (G drive) has the system and another drive (C drive) has the Boot. How this happened is beyond me. I also have a new formatted 2TB drive in a docking station and was trying to merge, but not sure how. How can I get the Boot and System onto the 2TB in the Docking state?

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen such a thing happen. I am not all certain you can just combine things together.

Windows 10 has specific partitions and just mashing the system drive onto the boot drive will not likely work.

Best suggestion at this point:  Pick your main drive (your 2 TB drive), make sure it is the only drive in the computer, use the Windows ISO or the manufacturer's Recovery USB (if there is one), and rebuild Windows 10.

Windows works best on one drive and splitting it up over more drives usually creates problems. My own experience is that one Windows drive is the best way.